# I have initialized git LFS in my repo and added extensions in the gitattribute for it to track but the size is still not reducing, what do I do?

Tags: bitbucket, large-files, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

My bit bucket repository has exceeded the** 4GB limit** so I initialized **git LFS** in my repo and added **extensions **in the **gitattribute** for it to track but the size only reduced by a few MB so I created **another repo** and copied the codes from the old repo to the new and it **reduced to 1.51GB** after which I made a commit and the size inflated to 2.1GB which means in no time the size will hit the 4GB again.

Please how do I manage this?

1. I first initialized git LFS in my old repo and added the extensions to the gitattribute but the size only reduced by a few MB.
2. I created **another repo** and copied the codes from the old repo to the new and it **reduced to 1.51GB** after which I made a commit and the size inflated to 2.1GB which means in no time the size will hit the 4GB again.